# Why am I getting "Invalid binary operator" warning when using modulus?

Tags: c#

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms app in Visual Studio for Mac. I noticed that when I use the modulus operator (%) I'm receiving a warning saying "Invalid binary operator", as you can see in the image below:

[image: Warning]

`maximum` and `step` variables are doubles.

Despite this the value of `x` is correctly calculated after this line.

**My question is:** what does it mean and why Why am I getting this warning?

Comment: Is this C#?  C++ will give you that error for modulus with doubles.

Comment: what are the types of maximum and step?

Comment: This appears to be generated by https://github.com/mono/debugger-libs/blob/master/Mono.Debugging/Mono.Debugging.Evaluation/NRefactoryExpressionEvaluatorVisitor.cs#L144  I believe it may be a bug in Xamarin, maybe?

Comment: @pm100 `maximum` and `step` are doubles.

Comment: @Amy, yes it seems to be a bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what does it mean

Nothing.  It's incorrect.  .Net supports modulus over doubles.

> Why am I getting this warning?

This appears to be a defect in Xamarin.  I would consider opening a ticket with them to solicit feedback from the development team.

https://github.com/mono/debugger-libs/blob/master/Mono.Debugging/Mono.Debugging.Evaluation/NRefactoryExpressionEvaluatorVisitor.cs#L144

Answer (score 2):

The little warning appears to be in error. I get no such warning when doing the same thing in VS2015. Modulo, in C#, is defined and valid on all of the numeric types. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h6zfzfy7(v=vs.100).aspx